# So I have this text file that I am working with, and I want to use the info in it for my parking system

Tags: python

A line from my text file:

```
RCF585 medium Joseph -you entered the parking lot at 3:30 and left at 4:30-
```

What I want to do is identify the car by the license number, and then know that it is "medium" (the size of it) and therefore the total cost for it is (parking cost * 1.25 (tax)) meanwhile the total for small is (parking cost * 1.00) and big (parking cost * 1.50).

The parking cost (20 usd per half an hour) depends of course on how much time the car have been parked so my second problem is how to read and identify how much a car has parked by reading the line of the relevant car. Here is what I have succeeded to write till now:

```
f=open(file, "r")

which_car= input("Please write your license number: ")

for line in f:

if line.startswith(which_car):        #identifying which car we want to deal with
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the cost for half an hour in the parking lot is 20 usd

Comment: you can edit your question to format the code properly and add this information ;)

Comment: okay now its done!

Comment: If you have to work with this format for the records, you can use `regex` (a powerful tool to find patterns in strings, that you could use to isolate reference, medium and times here); If you don't, you can use `csv` format, which is simpler to record and extract the same types of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **Regex** to find the *times* in the text,

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d\d)')
times = regex.findall(line)
```

and use **datetime** and **dateutil.relativedelta** to find the *parking time*,

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

parking_time = relativedelta(datetime.strptime(times[0] , '%H:%M'), datetime.strptime(times[1] , '%H:%M'))
minutes = abs((parking_time.hours * 60) + parking_time.minutes)
```

So, all together would be:

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    
    for line in f:

        if line.startswith(which_car):

            size = line.split(' ')[1]

            regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d\d)')
            times = regex.findall(line)
             
            # Update - Ex. 3:27 -> 3:30, 3:35 -> 3:30
            for i in range(len(times)):

                minute = int(times[i].split(':')[1])

                if minute - ((minute // 15) * 15) < 7.5:
                    minute = (minute // 15) * 15
                else:
                    minute = (minute // 15 + 1) * 15

                times[i] = times[i].split(':')[0] + ':' + str(minute)

            parking_time = relativedelta(datetime.strptime(times[0] , '%H:%M'), datetime.strptime(times[1] , '%H:%M'))

            minutes = abs((parking_time.hours * 60) + parking_time.minutes)

            parking_cost = (minutes // 30) * 20
            total_cost = parking_cost   # Default size is small

            if size == 'big':
                total_cost = parking_cost * 1.5
            elif size == 'medium':
                total_cost = parking_cost * 1.25
```

I suggest using *with* when working with files since you don't have to worry about closing the file manually anymore.

Comment: Wow! thank you for that. I just dont get what from (dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta) is for

Comment: btw I dont think it is working for me here in Pycharm

Comment: Ok I i fixed it and it works, but the parking cost that I am getting is wrong. I dont think the tax rate (1,25 and 1,50) are working because I am getting 40 usd for an hour of parking even though it is a medium or a big car

Comment: @Future dateutil.relativedelta library makes it easier to subtract those date-time objects. You could  also make your own function to find out the delta. Read more about the library [Here](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html). About your second comment, It works fine on Visual Studio

Comment: @Future, If I understood correctly: total_cost = parking_cost * tax_. the total_cost is what you are looking for

Comment: So I want that the parking cost (which is always 20 per half an hour) is gonna be multiplied with the tax rate to get a total cost. The total cost is always the same which is what bothers me. I will read the code again now.

Comment: Oh wait it was my fault I have figured it out!

Comment: It works now! I just wonder what I should use if I want to round it up meaning that if someone has parked from 3:30 till 4:15 it registers 2 half an hours, meanwhile if he parked till 4:14 it registers one half an hour

Comment: I think that can be made using divmode or something similiar. I will try to fix it till you have answered

Comment: Sure you can write a for loop and manipulate the times before passing them to relativedelta function

Comment: using divmod? Can you please write it? I havent been able to do it myself

Comment: @Future, Added a bit of code, hope it solves your problem. commented as 'Update'

Comment: Brother I understand what you have wrote in that for loop and it is pretty smart, but you are not using "minute" after the for loop. "minute" is not being used at all. I think you got confused between "minute" and "minutes". I still have the same problem. I am trying to solve it now

Comment: @Future My apologies, Fixed.

Comment: Its not working and I dont understand why. Everythink seems right but it refuses to work correctly. Still gives me the price of 1 half an hour when I park from 3:30 till 4:20 for example

Comment: @Future, you should change inside the `for` statement to fit your purpose, how you tent to round up the minute is up to you (Set your own conditions), I just wanted to give your a guideline of how you could implement it. This is going outside the scope of question, please post a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract the times, and [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the extracted strings into datetime data:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

which_car = input("Please write your license number: ")
file = "text.txt"

with open(file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(which_car):
            time1, time2 = re.findall("\d+:\d+", line)

def string_to_time(string):
    return datetime.strptime(string , '%H:%M')

print(string_to_time(time2) - string_to_time(time1))
```

Test run:

```
Please write your license number: RCF585
```

Output:

```
1:00:00
```

---

Explanation:

The pattern `\d+:\d+` means only digits on both sides of a colon, and the format `%H:%M` means an hour value and a minute value on opposite sides of a colon.

Note: it is a bad practice to assign an `open` call to a variable using the `=` operator. Instead, use the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement.

Comment: As you can see I am a beginner at programming but I will try and look into it. I will come back soon. Thank you

Comment: No I will try to do it by myself so I can learn, but I am just wondering if you can have a function inside a function?

Comment: Thank you. I am coming back in a couple of minutes

Comment: Wow this was very smart actually I understand it pretty well

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can read the size of the car from the file (the second word) and implement that as well in my parking system

Comment: @Future `line.split()[1]`

Comment: testing it now!